# Django forcing async database operation

Tags: python, django

```
raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
    django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

is thrown with following code

```
if object_query.exists():
```

object_query is

```
object_query = Example.objects.filter(
     name='test',
)
```

Comment: Can you post the code in which `object_query` is created? You're probably calling this from an async context. Check the relevant docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/#async-safety

Comment: Please make your question clear and also post the related code.